# Extremely slow boot time in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: boot

since 19.10 my system has become really sluggish to boot. I tried optimising my boot time by disabling services via systemd-analyze critical-chain and sudo systemctl mask so that now I have a nice boot time on paper

"Startup finished in 4.961s (firmware) + 3.923s (loader) + 2.227s (kernel) + 3.723s (userspace) = 14.836s 
graphical.target reached after 3.589s in userspace"

but when I measure the time it takes to boot "manually" I am still stuck at the smae 45 seconds mark between pressing the power button and being able to log-in as before.

Any idea what could cause such a long delay?